# Python Lambda Syntax with a letter variable

Tags: python, lambda

When I try to execute Lambda code I am not adept at determining what the "lettered" variables are for. Yes this one is for a W count (word count) but what does the E mean?

```
x = ['user', 'gym', 'spy', 'auto']
n_vowel = map(lambda w: w.count('e'), x)
print(list(n_vowel))
output is : [1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: It counts the letter `e` in each word. There's 1 `e` in first word and none in others.

Comment: It just mean that you count the number of letter **e** in each strings stored in the list **x**

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing magical about lambda arguments. It just so happens that most of the time a single letter is readable enough.

In this case, the `w` is one string from the list, and the `'e'` is for counting how many times `e` is in each word:

This might be clearer:

```
words = ['user', 'gym', 'spy', 'auto']
letter_to_count = 'e'
n_vowel = map(lambda word: word.count(letter_to_count), words)
print(list(n_vowel))
```

This is equivalent to

```
words = ['user', 'gym', 'spy', 'auto']
letter_to_count = 'e'
n_vowl = []
for word in words:
    n_vowl.append(word.count(letter_to_count))
print(n_vowl)
```